# How to create thumbnail images in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic, thumbnails, imaging

I found the best solution in [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/thumbtools2.aspx)

But to enable that, I need to register the com object first.

So is there any other way to create thumbnails with out using any third party?

In about example we have to use CxImageATL.dll. If we can't do without third party then, Is there any other way to use this dll with out registering the dll on server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CodeProject solution is a wrapper to the cxImage.dll. The problem is that you can not access the Windows API directly from ASP, so you need a third party (or your own) COM DLL.

If you don't want to register any object, I suggest you to use an ASP.net page to do the job of creating the thumbnail. Surely the server has ASP.net installed and you don't need to register anything.